# How to make work wkhtmltopdf library in Odoo v10

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, odoo-10, odoo

I have installed wkhtmltopdf using `sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf`.
But when i try to print a report getting an odoo warning:

```
Wkhtmltopdf failed (error code: -6). Message: The switch --header-spacing, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.The switch --header-html, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.The switch --footer-html, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.No protocol specified
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

How can i resolve this?

Comment: What does this question have to do with C++? Or Qt?

Comment: Those tags are suggested by stackoverflow.

Comment: That doesn't mean you _have_ to use them. You should use your brain to decide whether the suggestions are accurate. Stack Overflow is not psychic!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Odoo](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/install.html) website

> > Danger
> >
> > to print PDF reports, you must install wkhtmltopdf yourself:
> >     the version of wkhtmltopdf available in debian repositories does
> >     not support headers and footers so it can not be installed
> >     automatically. The recommended version is 0.12.1 and is available on
> >     the wkhtmltopdf download page, in the archive section. As there
> >     is no official release for Debian Jessie, you can find ours on the [extra](https://nightly.odoo.com/extra/) section of our nightly server.